# MPMediaPlayer-like framework in OSX environment

Tags: xcode5, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, nstableviewcell

I am happy to be back to develop after quite time.
So, I would like achieve an `NSTableView` with drag and drop capabilities. What I want to do is drag audio file (`mp3`, `car`, `aiff` and maybe `waw`) in a table and retrieve all information from files. Like author, bitrate, etc... and last but not less important are display artworks image. I wonder if I can add also preview player on art image (like a finder).

So in iOS environment this is a kids game through `MPMediaPlayer` framework, but in OSX environment that framework is unavailable. Yes, there are a lot of important other, but I need only retrieve files information and maybe play in place.

**Question is:** which kind of framework I can use that works like `MPMediaPlayer`? And is there a nice good path to follow for achieve this project? My goal is printing a `NSTableview` with my playlist.

Thanks a lot surely for help.

Comment: Take a look at the AVFoundation framework; it has a lot of functionality and can probably do what you need. It is available for both iOS and OS X. On OS X, you can also look at the QuickTime and QTKit frameworks, though these are now deprecated.

Comment: Thank you! I will try avfondation. Framework and QuickTime too